# Is $\mathbb{Z}_p \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}_p$ coherent?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras

The question is as in the title:

> Is  the ring $\mathbb{Z}_p \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}_p = \mathbb{Z}_p \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}} \mathbb{Z}_p$ coherent?

As shown in the [related question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/364678/is-mathbbq-p-otimes-mathbbq-mathbbq-p-coherent), the ring $\mathbb{Q}_p \otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} \mathbb{Q}_p$ *is* coherent, and so one cannot reduce to this case. (On the other hand $\mathbb{Q}_p \otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} \mathbb{Q}_p$ is not Noetherian, and so neither is $\mathbb{Z}_p \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}_p$). The flatness lemma used in the answer to the rational case does also not appear to be applicable in this case.

Comment: I am tempted to consider a more general question: Let $R$ be a DVR, and let $S$ be a flat $R$-algebra whose special and generic fibers are both coherent rings. Is $S$ a coherent ring?

Comment: Never mind, there are counterexamples to my more general question! More precisely, taking $R=\mathbf{R}[x]_{(x)}$ and $S=$germs of $C^\infty$ functions at $0 \in \mathbf{R}$ gives a counterexample. In this case, the special and generic fibers of $S$ are fields, but $S$ is not coherent.

Comment: Do we know the global dimension of $\mathbb{Z}_p \otimes_\mathbb{Z} \mathbb{Z}_p$? Is it $2$?

Comment: Dear Badam, I'm not sure, but it seems to be difficult/unknown. There is a paper of Auslander which considers the case of global dimension of algebras over a field, but this is as much as a I could find.

Comment: @DrewHeard right, I'm not even sure what gl. dim. of $\mathbb{Q}_p \otimes_\mathbb{Q} \mathbb{Q}_p$ is! Just thinking out loud because if we knew the gl. dim. to be small we might have coherence for free or at least an easier route to checking it.